# Empty specific div with the same class of several others on JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this problem, I generate a window (a div with the 'window' class) every time a link is clicked, this is the code for that:

```
$(".getWindow").live('click',function(){
    $('#desktop').append('<div class="window"><span class=\"close\">x</span>Well '+$(this).attr('well')+'<div id="screen"><img src="assembled_colors.jpeg" class="drag-image"  id="draggable"/></div></div>');
    $('.drag-image').draggable();
    $('.window').draggable();
});
```

Then, every time the 'x' in the second line of my code is pressed, I try to close the window, by doing this:

```
$('.close').live('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().empty();
});
```

This only closes what is inside of the window, but not the window itself, my next approach was to do this:

```
$('.close').live('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().empty();
});
```

Which closes all the opened windows. Could you please help me on how to close only the window containing the pressed x button?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.close').live('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

The reason for using [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) instead of [empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) is that empty() will affect what is contained within your parent element, whereas remove() will remove the parent element from the DOM.  This is why you are only removing the content within the window and not the actual window itself.

Answer (score 1):

[.empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) just clears the content of the selected element.
[.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) removes the element from the DOM.

I also suggest using [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), so it will still work if you introduce some additional elements later that wrap the close button

```
$('.close').live('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('.window').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change **`.empty()`** to **`.remove()`**

```
$('.close').live('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```